# How to convert dates from d/m/y to y-m-d in R

Tags: r, scripting

I have a dataset with a dates column in the format of  30/12/2020. What I need to do is to convert it to 2020-12-30 format using R script

Answer (score 2):

It is easier with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df1$dates <- dmy(df1$dates)
```

---

Or  using `base R`

```
df1$dates <- as.Date(df1$dates, '%d/%m/%Y')
```